# outdated tag (windows-defender)

Tags: bug, tags

It appears that the tag [windows-defender](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-defender) is a bit out of date. It states:

> In Windows 8, Windows Defender is a built in antivirus software product that replaces Microsoft Security Essentials. Before Windows 8, Windows Defender featured antispyware capabilities and was not offering antivirus protection.

It fails to mention that windows defender also exists in windows 10, which is where it is most commonly used now

Comment: I've updated the tag.